# Como fazer com que o componente window do Kendo UI feche ao se clicar no k-overlay?

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo

A empresa onde trabalho utiliza os componentes do Kendo UI e preciso fazer com que o componente window seja fechado ao se clicar no `k-overley` (backdrop do window), este componente está configurado para ter o comportamento de modal.

Veja minha chamada da directive do window:

```
<div kendo-window="ctrl.window" k-options="ctrl.options" k-content="{ url: '/window.html' }"></div>
```

As opções que estou passando na controller estão abaixo:

```
  vm.options = {
    modal: true,
  };
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma que encontrei para resolver este problema foi adicionando o atributo `k-on-activate` na directive com uma chamada para uma função na controller:

```
<div kendo-window="ctrl.window" k-options="ctrl.options" k-on-activate="ctrl.close()" k-content="{ url: '/window.html' }"></div>
```

A função ficou assim:

```
vm.close = function() {
  self = this;

  angular.element('.k-overlay').bind('click', function () {
    self.window.close();
  });
}
```

Está função adiciona um bind a classe `.k-overlay`, está classe é criada quando se ativa o componente window.

Espero estar ajudando outras pessoas que estão tendo a mesma necessidade.